# Safari for Iphone and Ipad self video get frozen if I set audio to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, streaming, webrtc

I have done a app video chat using webrtc api and jQuery JavaScript, but I have a issue in Safari on iPhone and iPad, the self video get frozen when I receiver the remote video, this only happen when I set audio to true on my settings,

```
 var constraint = {
        video: {
            minWidth: 270,
            minHeight: 270,
            minFrameRate: 25,
            maxWidth: 270,
            maxHeight: 270,
            maxFrameRate: 25,
            facingMode: 'user'
        },
        audio: false
    }
```

can someone help me pleases

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ iOS WebKit policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully work around, I separate the audio stream and video stream cloning my global stream and handle both on different way, here is the code help me to do that, I hope this help to someone.

```
function makeAudioOnlyStreamFromExistingStream(stream) {
  var audioStream = stream.clone();
  var videoTracks = audioStream.getVideoTracks();
  for (var i = 0, len = videoTracks.length; i < len; i++) {
    audioStream.removeTrack(videoTracks[i]);
  }
  console.log('created audio only stream, original stream tracks: ', stream.getTracks());
  console.log('created audio only stream, new stream tracks: ', audioStream.getTracks());
  return audioStream;
}

function makeVideoOnlyStreamFromExistingStream(stream) {
  var videoStream = stream.clone();
  var audioTracks = videoStream.getAudioTracks();
  for (var i = 0, len = audioTracks.length; i < len; i++) {
    videoStream.removeTrack(audioTracks[i]);
  }
  console.log('created video only stream, original stream tracks: ', stream.getTracks());
  console.log('created video only stream, new stream tracks: ', videoStream.getTracks());
  return videoStream;
}
function handleSuccess(stream) {
  var audioOnlyStream = makeAudioOnlyStreamFromExistingStream(stream);
  var videoOnlyStream = makeVideoOnlyStreamFromExistingStream(stream);
  // Do stuff with all the streams...
}
function handleError(error) {
  console.error('getUserMedia() error: ', error);
}
var constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: true,
};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

the full example is here

https://webrtchacks.com/guide-to-safari-webrtc/